# Which method gets called when we double tap the home button and send the app in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios9

Which method gets called when we **double tap** the home button and send the app in the background? I know that `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called when we press the home button once and send the `app` in the back ground. But I want to know the exact method which gets called when its double tapped.

Comment: `applicationWillResignActive:`

Answer (score 0):

```
-applicationWillResignActive:
```

For more details you can refer the apple documentation,
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive:]

But the tricky part here is you cannot be sure whether it is the double tap of the home button that has resulted in this function being called, as this function is also called when your app is interrupted by a phone call or sms etc.